# WordPress: Build valid query string from parameter array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On my site, the following array parameters will work fine through the WordPress query_posts() function in an ajax request:

```
 $arr_params= array
    (
     'post_type'=>'university',
      'tax_query' => array(
         array(
        'taxonomy' => 'uni',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'stanford'
        )
        )

    );
```

However is it possible to build a link using these arguments? I want to display a link on my posts, which when clicked, re-loads the WordPress loop using the above parameters.

I've tried

```
add_query_arg($arr_params,get_permalink());
```

but have not had any success

Comment: What is the finished URL supposed to look like? Your `$arr_params` has a couple of sub-arrays, and I can't figure out what correct query string ought to be.

Comment: I actually don't know what it should be. I was hoping it could be created magically, but I don't think get_permalink can handle the tax_query

Comment: You might be able to reverse engineer what the query would need to be, to get that array, but yes, I think it might be a little too complex for add_query_arg to do all the work.

Comment: thanks, just took a little experimentation and I got it pretty quickly...shame I posted the question, but maybe it will help somebody else

Comment: Could you add what you did as an answer? You can accept it when you get change, but I'm curious to see what you did!

Answer (score 1):

The add_query_arg function does not take a taxonomy query as seen in the question. The following array produced the result I wanted:

```
   $arr_params= array
    (
     'post_type'=>'university',
     'taxonomy' => 'uni',
     'terms' => 'stanford'
    );


echo add_query_arg($arr_params);
```

This is what it returns:

> /?post_type=university&taxonomy=uni&terms=stanford

Comment: yea I was kicking myself that I wrote a whole question before attempting that